# Java Convert dateTime to the given format

Tags: java, timezone, datetime-format, java.util.date, localdatetime

I need some help to convert the given local date time value (or util date) to one of the below formats with (ASIA/COLOMBO) time zone. Here are the formats (from one-signal API).

"Thu Sep 24 2015 14:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"

"September 24th 2015, 2:00:00 pm UTC-07:00"

"2015-09-24 14:00:00 GMT-0700"

"Sept 24 2015 14:00:00 GMT-0700"

"Thu Sep 24 2015 14:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"

Thanks.

Comment: *How* is a `LocalDateTIme` given? Is it a `java.time.LocalDateTime` or the one from joda time? Can you show your own attempts? Maybe, you are pretty near to get it working...

Comment: It is fetched from the database, java.time

Answer (score 4):

## `ZonedDateTime`

Instantiate a date, time, and zone into a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2015 , Month.SEPTEMBER , 24 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 14 , 0 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Colombo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

If given a `java.util.Date` object, convert to a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Apply a zone to move from UTC.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Colombo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

To produce text in your desired formats, use `DateTimeFormatter` class. This has been addressed many many times already on Stack Overflow. So search for that class name to learn more.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss OOOO" ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

> 2015-09-24 14:00:00 GMT+05:30

## ISO 8601

Those formats you showed are all *terrible* choices. When exchanging date-time values as text, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The standard formats are designed to be easy to parse by machine, and easy to read by humans across cultures.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll check it out, it would be better if you can provide me a pattern for one of the given.

Comment: @TharinduEranga There's one for you. Study the `DateTimeFormatter` Javadoc to learn the formatting pattern codes. Even better: Educate the publisher of your data about ISO 8601.

Answer (score 1):

The java.time classes were introduced in 1.8 and allows for more flexible and concise code.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
ZonedDateTime dateTime = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Colombo"));
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E M d u HH:mm:ss OOOO (z)");

// Using a format to convert at Temporal to a string
String formattedDate = format.format(dateTime);

// Using a format to convert a string to a Instant
Instant parsedDate = Instant.from(format.parse(formattedDate));
```

You can specify your date's format using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` or one of the many constants defined in DateTimeFormatter. The [pattern I created](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) matches your first example.

## The old method

These classes are yet to be deprecated and I find to be more straight forward for simple cases than the modern method.

java.text.SimpleDateFormat; It can handle going to and from a String and java.util.Date Object.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (z)");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo"));
// Note that the current date and time will be used when instantiating a new Date object.
String formattedDate = format.format(new Date());

try {
    Date parsedDate = format.parse(formattedDate);
} catch (ParseException exception) {
    // Handle malformed date
}
```

You will just have to [create the pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for any format you'd like to use.

EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (z) = Thu Sep 24 2015 14:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

Comment: Those terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java,time* classes defined in JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2020 is poor advice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you provide me a new solution for above, as @BasilBourque mentioned that if those are fairly old.

Comment: Almost there. In my locale I got `tor. 5 21 2020 00:50:05 GMT+05:30 (IST)`. You want to supply a locale for the formatter, and you want `MMM` for month abbreviation. And `'GMT'xx` will give you `GMT+0530` without the colon.